# Where does Android Studio save apks on device when running "Debug app"?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm running Android Studio 0.5.8 and using the "Debug App" functionality to send my work in progress to my phone to test.  I've done this dozens, maybe hundreds of times.  I'm concerned that Android Studio may not be overwriting the old apk files.  It appears that my useable space keeps dropping.

- Where does Android Studio save apks when installing debug runs?
- Is it a destructive or cumulative process? Do I need to clean out the folder manually?

Comment: Android studio doesn't store things on the device - it basically uses the ADB install command to ask ADB and the package manager to.  It's supposed to install over the old copy, at least conceptually.

Answer (score 0):

Within your module directory should be a folder called build, then another directory called APK. The APK should be in there. Perhaps check the file size and compare it to your "drop in space"

On your device Chris Stratton's comment is correct, it will overwrite the old APK when installing.

Check Settings->Apps and select your app. The see what readings it gives you for Data and cache.

Answer (score 0):

It is stored in `/data/local/tmp`. It should overwrite the old apks stored there.